# Как взять значение из TextBox и записать его в поле бд с типом данных "Дата и время"

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, ms-access

Подскажите пожалуйста, как взять значение из textBox и записать его в поле бд с типом данных "Дата и время"?

Вот как делаю я, но понятное дело строку в дату не впихнуть:

```
string zapr = "INSERT INTO СведенияОбУчениках (Дата_рождения) VALUES "+ "('" + Convert.ToString(c1_tb.Text) + "')";
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(zapr, myConnection);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Где:

- СведенияОбУчениках - таблица в бд
- Дата_рождения - поле с типом "Дата    и время"
- c1_tb - TextBox с введенными данными типа "02.03.2019"

Comment: Всегда используйте [параметры](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter?view=netframework-4.7.2) вместо конкатенации строк. Задайте нужный тип [OleDbType.DBTimeStamp](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbtype?view=netframework-4.7.2). Используйте [DateTime.Parse](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=netframework-4.7.2) (или TryParse).

Comment: Какой gui-фреймворк используете? WinForms? Возьмите компонент DateTimePicker вместо TextBox для ввода даты.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Извини за навязчивость, но не мог бы ты привести пример на моем примере, как использовать параметры вместо сложения строк?

Comment: @Кирилл Миронов, можете здесь увидеть как применять параметры

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во избежание [sql-инъекций](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0) всегда используйте [параметризованные](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter?view=netframework-4.7.2) запросы.

Задайте параметру нужный тип из перечисления [OleDbType](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbtype?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Чтобы преобразовать стороку из текстбокса в тип DateTime используйте методы этого класса [Parse](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=netframework-4.7.2) или [TryParse](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2).

И наконец, освобождайте ресурсы. Для этого в примере используется оператор [using](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement).

```
string query = "INSERT INTO СведенияОбУчениках (Дата_рождения) VALUES (?)";
using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, myConnection))
{
    command.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.DBTimeStamp).Value = DateTime.Parse(c1_tb.Text);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

---

Используйте для ввода даты компонент [DateTimePicker](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker?view=netframework-4.7.2) вместо TextBox.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public void InsertStudentInformation(String connectionString)
    {
        using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO СведенияОбУчениках (Дата_рождения) VALUES (@dataBirth)";
                command.Parameters
                    .Add("@dataBirth", OleDbType.DBTimeStamp)
                    .Value = DateTime.Parse(c1_tb.Text);
                connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
```