# Как записать дату/время в Access с C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

При нажатии на кнопку должно происходить действие записи в Базу Данных актуальной даты и времени. Допустим нажму на кнопку в 17:49 5 апреля 2020, то запись должна быть этой даты и времени. Как осуществить?
Подключение самой БД происходит так:

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=workers.mdb;");
```

Comment: Запись должна осуществляться не абы куда, на деревню дедушке, а в конкретную таблицу и столбец, который имеет нужный тип данных для этого.

Comment: соответственно нужно к OleDbConnection до писать OleDbCommand.

Comment: Я знаю, что запись должна быть куда-то, у меня для этого есть столбец w_connect с типом Дата и время

Comment: а в OleDbCommand передать нужную команду, типа insert into TableName(param1,...) values(value1,...);.

Comment: посмотрите этот ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/951537/261244

Comment: Yaroslav с тобой как-то связаться можно?